# Huge apk filesize when using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, filesize

I am building a prototype app with OpenCV. The app currently does not do anything but its apk file size is 6MB. The size is 10 times of normal app size. Is there any way to reduce this size?

**Update:** I found out that as long as I use android native camera and interface with OpenCV in JNI/C++, the file size can be dependent on the methods you are using in the library. Current my test app with simple filter has size of 700K.

Comment: How to interface OpenCV in JNI/C++ in Android Studio?

Comment: @HarshitJain.. did you find any solutions to decrease the apk size? I tried using the below code in build.grade however, its giving me same size...!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can unzip your .apk file and find two versions of `opencv_java.so` under the `lib` folder. Each of them is about 5.6Mb.

Actually `opencv_java.so` is the OpenCV library. And it is hard task to reduce its size even to 4Mb. But you can easily remove second copy of `opencv_java.so` from your .apk if you don't need to support old ARMv5 and ARMv6 devices. (The simplest way to build your app without armeabi OpenCV libraries is removing all `libs/armeabi` folders from OpenCV package and rebuilding your application.)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Android Studio goto build.gradle of your app and add following lines inside `android {}`

```
productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        armv7a {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
}
```

This will allow you to create separate apk for separate architecture thus decrease the size of apk by alot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) to remove the code (from the "binary") that you are not using from OpenCV.

Comment: I just tried this but it didn't help. Can you show me an example of proguard.cfg and project.properties? What I tried is basically removed all -keep classes from proguard.cfg and put `proguard.config=proguard.cfg` in project.properties. But building produced the exact same size.

Comment: We use something very similar to [this one](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/ProGuard). You could try that.

Comment: Well, my project.properties has a line of `#android.library.reference.1=../../OpenCV-2.3.1` And I think the line is responsible for the filesize no matter what I do with proguard.

Comment: @dmon can you provide me full instructions on how to remove unused native code from open cv binary. as i am including open cv binary as shared lib in my project. means that I am using .so file that comes with open cv android sdk.