# Is it possible to copy individual image processing function out from opencv library?

Tags: android

My android app uses only two image processing functions in the OpenCV library - Gaussian blur and Adaptive Threshold.

The beta testers of my app all feel that it would be better if they don't need to download the seperate app, the OpenCV Manager before they can use my app. I could include the OpenCV library inside my app but my app would increase in size by 50Mb which is not very great..

Is it possible just to extract these two functions out? Or is there java source codes which could perform adaptive threshold on a Bitmap out there that can be used?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283206/huge-apk-filesize-when-using-opencv

Comment: I followed the link and tried the ProGuard way, it reduces my apk size from 28.8mb to 28.4mb, which is not that great :(
actually by using just Gaussian blur and Adaptive threshold it only adds 8mb to my final apk size so it is still not that bad.. 
Now I'm trying to reduce this 8mb to 4mb by removing the libs/armeabi-v7a folder and just use armeabi but OpenCV couldn't initialize on my Samsung Galaxy S3 after that, I wonder why?